# How to Remove Status Bar in "View Based Application" - iOS

Tags: ios, templates, xcode4, statusbar

This is a part of me trying to get used to working with XCode4...

OK, so i've created a new project in XCode 4 and I used the **View Based Application** template; I wish to build the new app as Apple intended me to use this template.

So I'm using the automatically-created-view-controller which is called from the AppDelegate (so far I haven't touched anything). Now, I want to **remove** the **STATUS BAR**. As far as I understand, what I should do, is go to the **view XIB** and in the **Attributes Inspector** set the **Status Bar** field to **None** (this is how I used to do it so far), but mercilessly when I run the application the STATUS BAR is still there (!).

I also tried to do the same thing on the **mainWindow.xib** file (the setting the STSTUS BAR attribute to None thing) and the app runs with this bar that blocks my view...

Anyone?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you read the "header" you will see "Simulated metrics". Those properties are only to simulate visual elements when you lay out your code with interfacebuilder.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

If you do it in the Application Delegate you write:

```
    [application setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

in this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {...}
```

### EDIT

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:

Requested in comment, from documentation:

> setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:
>
> Hides or shows the status bar,
>   optionally animating the transition.
>   - (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden
>   withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimation)animation
>   Parameters
>
> hidden
>
> ```
> YES to hide the status bar, NO to show the status bar. animation
>
> A constant that indicates whether there should be an animation and, if
> ```
>
> one is requested, whether it should
>   fade the status bar in or out or
>   whether it should slide the status bar
>   in or out.
>
> Discussion
>
> See the descriptions of the constants
>   of the UIStatusBarAnimation type for
>   more information. Availability
>
> ```
> * Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
> ```

So if you are not interested in the animation part I suggest using this:

> statusBarHidden
>
> A Boolean value that determines
>   whether the status bar is hidden.
>   @property(nonatomic,
>   getter=isStatusBarHidden) BOOL
>   statusBarHidden Return Value
>
> YES means the status bar is hidden; NO
>   means it's visible. Availability
>
> ```
> * Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```

Comment: thanks Andreas, it did hide the status bar (I used the second option you suggested); but I get a warning --- Deprecations: 'setStatusBarHidden:animated:' is deprecated --- any idea what it may be?

Comment: @Ohad: No problem, did not know that it was deprecated, I have updated the answer for you.