# How to handle alignment of UI on phone call?

Tags: iphone, ios5, user-interface, storyboard, alignment

I am developing iPhone app for iOS 5 or above version, and making use of storyboard for UI design. My problem is when i am on phone call my UI gets misaligned because my upper status bar is taking 20 to 30 pixel of screen space.

[image]

> How to handle my UI when i am on phone call?

Answer (score 2):

I finally got answer for my question. Following are the things i made changes in my project and everything started working fine.

1. Took sliced images of all the things needed in my UI. (Initially
   i was taking common image to save slicing time)
2. Made you of autoResizingMask property. It help me save my lots of time. Just make sure only  3 arrows top, left and right one is in ON state and your work is over.

For making everyones search easy i will add following Stackoverflow links to save your time

3. [How to position view below green bar during phone call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303997/how-to-position-view-below-green-bar-during-phone-call)
4. [Resize for in-call status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114557/resize-for-in-call-status-bar)
5. [How do I detect a double-height status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420410/how-do-i-detect-a-double-height-status-bar)
6. [How to Remove Status Bar in "View Based Application" - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485703/how-to-remove-status-bar-in-view-based-application-ios)
7. [how to hide status bar in Iphone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264072/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-iphone-application)
8. [How In-Call status bar impacts UIViewController's view size ? (and how to handle it properly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486491/how-in-call-status-bar-impacts-uiviewcontrollers-view-size-and-how-to-handle)
9. [iPhone Programming In Call Status Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987605/iphone-programming-in-call-status-bar)
10. [resize content after iPhone status bar is shown/hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067551/resize-content-after-iphone-status-bar-is-shown-hidden)
11. [How to programmatically get iOS status bar height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991935/how-to-programmatically-get-ios-status-bar-height)
12. [How is the in-call status bar impacting my CGAffineTransform'd view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864845/how-is-the-in-call-status-bar-impacting-my-cgaffinetransformd-view)
13. [View resize when In-Call Status Bar changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144642/view-resize-when-in-call-status-bar-changes)

Thanks to all the people who have replied to all the questions above. It made my big problem resolved.